# Prevent pitch correction of Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, web-audio-api

I have an audio using Web Audio API and want to record it at half the speed and later speed it up to normal at back-end. The output I get is pitched down.

```
var mr = null;
var source = null;
var stop = function(){
    mr.stop();
    source.stop();
}
var save = function(blob, filename){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = filename || 'data.json';
    link.click();
}
var context = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )();
var dest = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
function loadSound(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  // Decode asynchronously
  request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.playbackRate.value = 0.5;
        source.connect(dest);
        mr = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);
        mr.start();
        source.start(0);
        var chunks = [];
        mr.ondataavailable = function(e){
          chunks.push(e.data);
        }
        mr.onstop = function(e) {
          var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' });
          save(blob,"a.webm");
        }
        setTimeout(stop, 10000);
    }, null);
  }
  request.send();
}
loadSound("https://storage.googleapis.com/frulix-dev.appspot.com/words");
```

I have created a fiddle for the case https://jsfiddle.net/thenectorgod/v3ogtwvp/4/.

It does not happen for normal  recording containing audio and that audio comes clear after speeding to 2.

Can anyone suggest how to get proper audio in this case?

Comment: I ended up using audio tag. But I still want an answer for this as I want some more control on the audio.